# Spam, spam, [spammer] and [spam]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags for spam:

- [spam](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam), 316 questions
- [spammer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spammer), 17 question

While I understand the difference between the person who sends the spam and the spam itself, that is not a meaningful distiction for a pair of tags. And taking a glance at the question, it is not reflected in their topics.

So could we perhaps merge the two or just burninate [spammer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spammer) or something similar? When it comes to spam, I think that one is enough.

Comment: Agreed, that was a complete subset - every post with [spammer] also already had [spam], so completely useless. Thanks!

Comment: @AviD Sounds like somebody was spamming tags.

Comment: Spam, spam, spam, sausage, and spam sandwich!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AviD has turned [spammer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spammer) into a synonym of [spam](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam). Problem solved.

Comment: Posting this so there can be an accepted answer.

Comment: Now, we just need to make sure [ham] and [eggs] are synonyms, too. :-)

Comment: @Arminius do you mean [ham] and [hammer]?